# I'm looking for a way to make a function ignore a substring that was already analyzed

Tags: c++

Basically, I have this function:

```
int countFreq(string pat, string txt)
{
    int M = pat.length();
    int N = txt.length();
    int res = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i <= N - M; i++)
    {
        int j;
        for (j = 0; j < M; j++)
            if (txt[i + j] != pat[j])
                break;
        if (j == M)
        {
            res++;
        }
    }
    return res;
}
```

Which basically checks the number of times a pattern appears in a string. Now, the problem is that if the pattern is "121", and the string is "12121212", it will find 3 "121" substrings ("`121`2`121`2" and the one in the middle), but I don't want it to do that, it shouldn't take in consideration the one in the middle, so it should only find 2 substrings, not 3.

How should I do something like that?

Comment: Hi and welcome to stackoverflow, maybe try this implementation: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/frequency-substring-string/

Comment: In the condition `if (j == M)` add line to `i += M - 1`, so that you'll start checking from the next character

Answer (score 1):

You can just make the index skip the length of the pattern (minus 1, because it automatically increments by 1) to skip the rest of the string and prevent additional matches.

```
    for (int i = 0; i <= N - M; i++)
    {
        int j;
        for (j = 0; j < M; j++)
            if (txt[i + j] != pat[j])
                break;
        if (j == M)
        {
            res++;
            i += M - 1; // Skip the rest of the string
        }
    }
```